# 'The Property Content is set more than once' on Rg.Plugins.Popup Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to mobile development...and am converting a `Xamarin.Forms` project into a `.NETStandard` library.  The original programmer is using `Rg.Plugins.Popup` (for popup pages).

I am seeing the following **Design-Time** error...

[image: Design-Time Error]

SIDE NOTES:

- The pages "xaml.cs" file shows no design-time
- The view does reference-in another `ContentView`...but that "view" isn't showing any errors.

**THE VIEW:**
Here is the entire view.  Any insight is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
                 xmlns:forms1="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
                 xmlns:popupViews="clr-namespace:ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.ViewContent.PopupViews;assembly=ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile"
                 xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 x:Class="ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Views.GeneralPopupPage" 
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent">

    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation PositionIn="Bottom" PositionOut="Center" ScaleIn="1" ScaleOut="0.7" DurationIn="700" EasingIn="BounceOut" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    
    <ScrollView
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Frame
                x:Name="FrameContainer"
                Margin="15"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="White">
                <StackLayout
                    IsClippedToBounds="True"
                    Padding="10, 5"
                    Spacing="3"
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    HeightRequest="320">

                    <!-- Content -->
                    <popupViews:CircuitTechView x:Name="viewCircuitTech" IsVisible="{Binding IsViewCircuitTechVisible}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    <forms1:AnimationView 
                        x:Name="animationView"
                        Animation="animation-w320-h320.json"
                        Loop="False" 
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        IsVisible="False"
                        Speed=".7"
                        OnFinish="AnimationView_OnOnFinish"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        WidthRequest="175">
                    </forms1:AnimationView>


                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, -1, -1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseAllCommand}"/>
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>

                <Image
                    x:Name="CloseImage"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <OnPlatform
                            x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                            Android="close_circle_button.png"
                            iOS="close_circle_button.png"
                            WinPhone="Assets/close_circle_button.png"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>

                /* HERE IS WHERE ITHE ISSUE IS */
                <forms:SvgCachedImage 
                    Source="resource://ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Images.close.svg" 
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30">
                    <forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseAllCommand}" CommandParameter="emptyValue" />
                    </forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </forms:SvgCachedImage>

            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentView can only have one child/layout.

Like the error implies, "The property is set more than once", you have 2 images (which in this case count as a layout or child), and you have to place them inside the layout you prefer (StackLayout, Grid, AbsoluteLayout, etc...)

This way you will only have one Layout as a child inside the ContentView, like so:

```
<ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, -1, -1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseAllCommand}"/>
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>

            <StackLayout>
                <Image
                    x:Name="CloseImage"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <OnPlatform
                            x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                            Android="close_circle_button.png"
                            iOS="close_circle_button.png"
                            WinPhone="Assets/close_circle_button.png"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>

                <!-- No more issues in your layout :) -->
                <forms:SvgCachedImage 
                    Source="resource://ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Images.close.svg" 
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30">
                    <forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseAllCommand}" CommandParameter="emptyValue" />
                    </forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </forms:SvgCachedImage>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
```

You can see more of this error [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179935/error-message-the-propery-content-is-set-more-than-once)

And also some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts) that can be useful to you.

Comment: I am EXTREMELY new to Mobile...so thanks for providing the example

Answer (score 2):

your innermost `ContentView` contains two elements, an `Image` and a `SvgCachedImage`.  If you want to have multiple children, you need to place them in a layout container

Comment: Sorry...but I am new to this.  Are you saying they each need their own StackLayout container?

Comment: so, I am saying that a ContentView can have ONE child.  If you want multiple children, you need to place them in a container (a layout of some sort), which can have multiple children.  So the ContentView would contain a (for instance) StackLayout, and the StackLayout would contain the two image controls